# Python simple ProcessPoolExecutor example wont work

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying out multithreading in Python 3, but I can't figure out why my example won't work. It should just print the numbers and as confirmation print the number again.
But it runs into many errors.

```
from concurrent import futures

def print_me(num):
    print('Zahl: ' + str(num))
    return num


def say_bye(job):
    num = job.result()
    print(str(num) + ' is out!')


def test_multi():
    num_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        for num in num_list:
            job = executor.submit(print_me, num)
            job.add_done_callback(say_bye(job))

test_multi()
```

Theoretically, instead of:

```
for num in num_list:
    job = executor.submit(print_me, num)
    job.add_done_callback(say_bye(job))`
```

I could use this, or?

```
executor.map(print_me, num_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the code running i just need to add:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_multi()
```